# Set EditText error to null on every character

Tags: android

I have an EditText which takes number input I have a regex of that number if the user enters the wrong number inside that EditText the error appears below the EditText, but I want to check every typed number in that EditText for example if a user types the wrong number which is not in regex the error should appear and if he removes that number and enter correct number the error should disappear, in my case after he enters all the remaining numbers the error disappears. I want to apply the validation on every number typed to make the error appear and disappear.

Here's my code.

```
        @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.length() <= 12) {

            if (editMobileNumber.getText().toString() != null) {
                if (focus) {
                    if (!s.toString().startsWith("971")) {
                        editMobileNumber.setText("971");
                        Selection.setSelection(editMobileNumber.getText(), editMobileNumber.getText().length());
                    } else {
                        tvMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                if (editMobileNumber.getText().toString().length() <= 12) {

                    if (s.length() > 3) {

                        if (UtilHelper.isValidUAENumber(editMobileNumber.getText().toString())) {
                            tvMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            if(editMobileNumber.getText().toString().length() <= 12){
                                tvMobileNumber.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_number_should_be));
                                tvMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        tvMobileNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            String text = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
            editMobileNumber.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
            editMobileNumber.setSelection(editMobileNumber.getText().length());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is focus in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puh, there is a lot of stuff ongoing here.
First of all, `afterTextChanged` is called after the user enters some text or in your case number.
In your `else` case you a changing your text again.

```
String text = editMobileNumber.getText().toString();
editMobileNumber.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
```

Why are you doing this? There is no need for that, right?

Next thing, you only compare your input if the length is <= 12 characters

```
if (s.length() <= 12)
```

But if I get you right, I want do it every time, right? Even when you enter a number that is for example 14 characters long, right? Then you should change this first.

Your should also think about to exclude `editMobileNumber.getText().toString()` into an own variable to make your code more readable.

Next thing is, that you only validate the input with `UtilHelper.isValidUAENumber` if the length is at least 4 characters.

```
if (s.length() > 3) {
```

I think also this is not what you expect.

So again, there is a lot of stuff that is going on here. Probably you should check your whole logic again and try to understand each step. Try to reduce the logic first and then improve the code step by step.